# JavaScript: Concatenate 3D array into 2D array, wrapping values in html tags

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

**3D array**

```
// Array

var x = {
  "letter": [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i" ],
  "line": [
    { "data": [ 306, 830, 377, 651, 547, 369, 300, 148, 494 ] },
    { "data": [ 88, 339, 298, 87, 96, 108, 93, 182, 64 ] },
    { "data": [ 3157, 2943, 2724, 2116, 3700, 2980, 2449, 2494, 1057 ] },
    { "data": [ 2006, 1921, 2030, 615, 273, 415, 680, 286, 730 ] }
    ]
  };
```

**Some variables**

```
// Variables

var line = x.line;
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
  data.push(line[i].data);
  }
```

**The actual code in question**

```
// Existing code (only works on fixed number of array objects, but I want something that will work on any number of objects)

var listData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < line.length; i++) { listData.push(''); }
for (var i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
  listData[0] += '<li>' + data[0][i] + '</li>';
  listData[1] += '<li>' + data[1][i] + '</li>';
  listData[2] += '<li>' + data[2][i] + '</li>';
  listData[3] += '<li>' + data[3][i] + '</li>';
  }

// Perhaps something like this? This is where I got stuck...

var listData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
  listData.push('');
  listData[i] += '<li>' + data[i][/* ??? */] + '</li>';
  }
```

I want to simplify the `line[data]` objects into one array, wrapping each of the `data` objects' values in an html `<li>` tag, then concatenating them into one string per object. So that `listData` looks like below:

**Desired result**

```
listData == [
"<li>306</li><li>830</li><li>377</li><li>651</li><li>547</li><li>369</li><li>300</li><li>148</li><li>494</li>",
"<li>88</li><li>339</li><li>298</li><li>87</li><li>96</li><li>108</li><li>93</li><li>182</li><li>64</li>",
"<li>3157</li><li>2943</li><li>2724</li><li>2116</li><li>3700</li><li>2980</li><li>2449</li><li>2494</li><li>1057</li>",
"<li>2006</li><li>1921</li><li>2030</li><li>615</li><li>273</li><li>415</li><li>680</li><li>286</li><li>730</li>"
]
```

**But I want to do it in a way that would work not just with 4 data objects, but any number of them originally in `x`.**

You can see that I did it with the 4 objects that are there, but can't figure out how to do it programmatically. If you can please use my existing variables, I'd be extra appreciative! Thanks.

Comment: Do you want `<li>306></li>...<li>88</li>...`?

Comment: @AmitJoki No; see the CodePen.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you added the desired output to your question; having to look at your demo elsewhere is an unnecessary step: demos are for supporting your question, not a replacement for them.

Comment: @DavidThomas exactly +1

Comment: @DavidThomas I tried adding in my code via the Code Snippets tool, but it was not working. That's why I included the CodePen originally. I have now updated the question with my code and desired output in blocks, per your advice.

Comment: Thank you, I've retracted my close vote. Use of a live demo is a great additional resource, but while there will always be those asking 'for a JS Fiddle,' they're not obligatory (though they are helpful), asking a complete question is, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map`. First you get the data into a multidimensional array, then you create `li` for each number:

```
var listData = x.line
  .map(function(obj){return obj.data})
  .map(function(ns){return '<li>'+ ns.join('</li><li>') +'</li>'})
```

This will work with any number of data objects, containing an array of any number of items.